# Fractions Input in metaboxes

Tags: html, wordpress, user-input

I'm using a input type="number" for my metabox, which works fine when you enter a new item and publish but going back to that same post and trying to update anything, it won't allow it and displays 'Invalid Input' next the fraction.  I didn't know this was not supported thought type number meant all numbers, including fractions but what's confusing is why does the browser allow it to be posted but not updated since the value is already there? What's the best way to patch this up, making it into a text input instead?

[image: HTML5 number input invalid value when trying to save a fraction]

Comment: what browser is this in?

Comment: It was happening in all browsers that support the number type field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some digging around I found the answer to my question, use steps to declare incremental values, worked as expected.  More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float.positive